# Update query causing System Lock state in MySQL

Tags: mysql

whenever we run the below particular update query it's taking more time, and also I always find the state of the query as System Lock in the show processlist. I do find the system lock state even though there are no other DML or DDL queries getting executed. Please suggest resolving the issue. If required I can share the indexes and table structure.

```
UPDATE jobs_feed 
    SET posted_to_gfj = 10 
WHERE jobtitle NOT REGEXP "[+|^||||*|<|>|||^|%|!|â€“]|[ ]{2,}" 
AND postalcode!="" 
AND occupationalcategory!="" 
AND companyKeywords!="" 
AND locationKeywords !="" 
AND posted_to_gfj=0 
AND reposted_to_gfj=0 
AND cpa!=0 
AND is_deleted!=1 
AND company NOT IN ("AyaHealthcare","AdventHealth","BetterHelp","UnitedHealth Group") 
AND job_status!=0 
AND job_status!=3 
AND deleted_from_gfj!=1 
AND deleted_date_from_gfj IS NULL 
AND  ROUND ((LENGTH(location)- LENGTH( REPLACE ( location, ",", ""))) / LENGTH(","))=2 
AND employerId IN ("emp-mh-appcast") 
AND locExpand=1 
ORDER BY cpa DESC 
limit 14390;
```

Comment: Why do you have a Sort and a Limit on an UPDATE query?

Comment: This query runs every four hours and they want to update higher "cpa" value rows. And they want to update only those limited rows in one run.  Please suggest me if they are causing the issue